# How to use your keyboard layout on Parallels Desktop? (This is the third time I ask)

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-layout, parallels

I have made a custom keyboard layout using Ukelele. Using Parallels desktop is a pain since them because the keys are different from what I'm used to. How do I use that keyboard layout on Parallels?

Comment: I've been asking that for long without answers. Please I really need this. Can't be possible I'm the only one using parallels desktop with a custom keyboard layout on OSX!

Comment: It will be something in the emulated OS, I would probably start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)

Comment: Yes I've just spent the last hour configuring it. Even so, I had to partially use Autohotkey and run some commands on OSX Lion to disable Caps Lock sync. It's nice now. So bad I'll have to change it twice when I redesign my layout.